# access a value returned by partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Working in asp.net and c#.

I have a partial class in my application.One of the methods of this class returns a value( **value is a dataset**) like **return value;**

example code:

```
      public partial class CommonClass : IDisposable
      {
        public static dataset somemethod(string somevariable)
          {

             //some code


             return variable;

          }


      }
```

Now i want to access the value of **variable** in my codebehind.How can i do that.please give some sugessions..

**NOTE**:variable is a dataset..

Comment: Where is `variable` declared? As you could globalize the declaration. Or you should use the return value of your function.

Comment: i want to use return value(variable in my example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just like this you can do it as **method is static there is no need to create any instance of class you can call it as below**

```
DataSet  ds =CommonClass.somemethod("mydata") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the static method `somemethod` of your class `CommonClass`. You can read more about static and instance methods **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**.

```
DataSet ds = CommonClass.somemethod("somevalue");
```